# Errors encountered in partial_fit in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

On training with a partial_fit function in scikit learn I get the following error without the program terminating , how is that possible and what are the repurcussions of this even though the trained model behaves correctly and gives correct output. Is this something to worry about?

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py:207: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  self.class_log_prior_ = (np.log(self.class_count_)
```

I am using the following modified training function as I have to maintain a constant list of labels\classes as the partial_fit does not allow adding new classes\labels on subsequent runs , the class prior is same in each batch of training data:

```
class MySklearnClassifier(SklearnClassifier):
    def train(self, labeled_featuresets,classes=None, partial=True):
        """
        Train (fit) the scikit-learn estimator.

        :param labeled_featuresets: A list of ``(featureset, label)``
            where each ``featureset`` is a dict mapping strings to either
            numbers, booleans or strings.
        """

        X, y = list(compat.izip(*labeled_featuresets))
        X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
        y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)



        if partial:
            classes=self._encoder.fit_transform(list(set(classes)))
            self._clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=list(set(classes)))
        else:
            self._clf.fit(X, y)

        return self
```

Also on the second call to partial_fit it throws following error for class count=2000 , and training samples are 3592 on calling  model = self.train(featureset, classes=labels,partial=partial):

```
self._clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=list(set(classes)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 277, in partial_fit
    self._count(X, Y)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 443, in _count
    self.feature_count_ += safe_sparse_dot(Y.T, X)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2000,11430) (2000,10728) (2000,11430)
```

Where am I going wrong based on the error thrown? Does it mean that I am pushing in incorrect dimensioned data ?
I tried following , I am now calling :

```
        X = self._vectorizer.transform(X)
        y = self._encoder.transform(y)
```

each time the partial fit is called. Earlier I used fittransform for each partialfit call. Is this correct

```
class MySklearnClassifier(SklearnClassifier):
    def train(self, labeled_featuresets, classes=None, partial=False):
        """
        Train (fit) the scikit-learn estimator.

        :param labeled_featuresets: A list of ``(featureset, label)``
            where each ``featureset`` is a dict mapping strings to either
            numbers, booleans or strings.
        """

        X, y = list(compat.izip(*labeled_featuresets))

        if partial:
            classes = self._encoder.fit_transform(np.unique(classes))
            X = self._vectorizer.transform(X)
            y = self._encoder.transform(y)
            self._clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=list(set(classes)))
        else:
             X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
             y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)
             self._clf.fit(X, y)

        return self._clf
```

After many tries I was able to get the following code working, by accounting for first call but I had assumed that the classifier pickled files would be increasing in size after each iteration but I am getting the same sized pkl file for each batch which is not possible:

```
 class MySklearnClassifier(SklearnClassifier):

    def train(self, labeled_featuresets, classes=None, partial=False,firstcall=True):
        """
        Train (fit) the scikit-learn estimator.

        :param labeled_featuresets: A list of ``(featureset, label)``
            where each ``featureset`` is a dict mapping strings to either
            numbers, booleans or strings.
        """

        X, y = list(compat.izip(*labeled_featuresets))

        if partial:

           if firstcall:
                classes = self._encoder.fit_transform(np.unique(classes))
                X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
                y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)
                self._clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=classes)
           else:

                X = self._vectorizer.transform(X)
                y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)
                self._clf.partial_fit(X, y)
        else:
             X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
             y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)
             self._clf.fit(X, y)

        return self
```

here is the entire code:

```
class postagger(ClassifierBasedTagger):
    """
    A classifier based postagger.
    """
    #MySklearnClassifier()
    def __init__(self, feature_detector=None, train=None,estimator=None,

                 classifierinstance=None, backoff=None,
                 cutoff_prob=None, verbose=True):

        if backoff is None:
            self._taggers = [self]
        else:
            self._taggers = [self] + backoff._taggers
        if estimator:
            classifier = MySklearnClassifier(estimator=estimator)
            #MySklearnClassifier.__init__(self, classifier)
        elif classifierinstance:
            classifier=classifierinstance






        if feature_detector is not None:
            self._feature_detector = feature_detector
            # The feature detector function, used to generate a featureset
            # or each token: feature_detector(tokens, index, history) -> featureset

        self._cutoff_prob = cutoff_prob
        """Cutoff probability for tagging -- if the probability of the
           most likely tag is less than this, then use backoff."""

        self._classifier = classifier
        """The classifier used to choose a tag for each token."""

        # if train and picklename:
        #     self._train(classifier_builder, picklename,tagged_corpus=train, ONLYERRORS=False,verbose=True,onlyfeatures=True ,LOADCONSTRUCTED=None)

    def legacy_getfeatures(self, tagged_corpus=None, ONLYERRORS=False, existingfeaturesetfile=None, verbose=True,
                           labels=artlabels):

        featureset = []
        labels=artlabels
        if not existingfeaturesetfile and tagged_corpus:
            if ONLYERRORS:

                classifier_corpus = open(tagged_corpus + '-ONLYERRORS.richfeature', 'w')
            else:
                classifier_corpus = open(tagged_corpus + '.richfeature', 'w')

            if verbose:
                print('Constructing featureset  for training corpus for classifier.')
            nlp = English()
            #df=pandas.DataFrame()
            store = HDFStore('featurestore.h5')



            for sentence in sPickle.s_load(open(tagged_corpus,'r')):
                untagged_words, tags, senindex = zip(*sentence)
                doc = nlp(u' '.join(untagged_words))
                # untagged_sentence, tags , rest = unpack_three(*zip(*sentence))
                for index in range(len(sentence)):
                    if ONLYERRORS:
                        if tags[index] == '<!SAME!>' and random.random() < 0.05:
                            featureset = self.new_feature_detector(doc, index)
                            sPickle.s_dump_elt((featureset, tags[index]), classifier_corpus)
                            featureset['label']=tags[index]
                            featureset['senindex']=str(senindex[0])
                            featureset['wordindex']=index
                            df=pandas.DataFrame([featureset])
                            store.append('df',df,index=False,min_itemsize = 150)
                            # classifier_corpus.append((featureset, tags[index]))
                        elif tags[index] in labels:
                            featureset = self.new_feature_detector(doc, index)
                            sPickle.s_dump_elt((featureset, tags[index]), classifier_corpus)
                            featureset['label']=tags[index]
                            featureset['senindex']=str(senindex[0])
                            featureset['wordindex']=index
                            df=pandas.DataFrame([featureset])
                            store.append('df',df,index=False,min_itemsize = 150)


                        # classifier_corpus.append((featureset, tags[index]))
        # else:
        #     for element in sPickle.s_load(open(existingfeaturesetfile, 'w')):
        #         featureset.append( element)

        return tagged_corpus + '.richfeature'

    def _train(self, featuresetdata, classifier_builder=MultinomialNB(), partial=False, batchsize=500):
        """
        Build a new classifier, based on the given training data
        *tagged_corpus*.

        """



        #labels = set(cPickle.load(open(arguments['-k'], 'r')))
        if partial==False:
           print('Training classifier FULLMODE')
           featureset = []
           for element in sPickle.s_load(open(featuresetdata, 'r')):
               featureset.append(element)

           model = self._classifier.train(featureset, classes=artlabels, partial=False,firstcall=True)
           print('Training complete, dumping')
           try:
            joblib.dump(model,  str(featuresetdata) + '-FULLTRAIN ' + slugify(str(classifier_builder))[:10] +'.mpkl')
            print "joblib dumped"
           except:
               print "joblib error"
           cPickle.dump(model, open(str(featuresetdata) + '-FULLTRAIN ' + slugify(str(classifier_builder))[:10] +'.cmpkl', 'w'))
           print('dumped')
           return
        #joblib.dump(self._classifier,str(datetime.datetime.now().hour)+'-naivebayes.pickle',compress=0)

        print('Training classifier each batch of {} training points'.format(batchsize))

        for i, batchelement in enumerate(batch(sPickle.s_load(open(featuresetdata, 'r')), batchsize)):
            featureset = []
            for element in batchelement:
                featureset.append(element)



            # model =  super(postagger, self).train (featureset, partial)
            # pdb.set_trace()
            # featureset = [item for sublist in featureset for item in sublist]
            trainsize = len(featureset)
            print("submitting {} training points for training\neg last one:".format(trainsize))
            for d, l in featureset:
                if len(d) != 113:
                    print d
                    assert False

            print featureset[-1]
            # pdb.set_trace()
            try:
                if i==0:
                    model = self._classifier.train(featureset, classes=artlabels, partial=True,firstcall=True)
                else:
                    model = self._classifier.train(featureset, classes=artlabels, partial=True,firstcall=False)

            except:
                type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
                traceback.print_exc()
                pdb.post_mortem(tb)

            print('Training for batch {} complete, dumping'.format(i))
            cPickle.dump(model, open(
                str(featuresetdata) + '-' + slugify(str(classifier_builder))[
                                            :10] + 'UPDATED batch-{} of {} points.mpkl'.format(
                    i, trainsize), 'w'))
            print('dumped')
        #joblib.dump(self._classifier,str(datetime.datetime.now().hour)+'-naivebayes.pickle',compress=0)

    def untag(self,tagged_sentence):
        """
        Given a tagged sentence, return an untagged version of that
        sentence.  I.e., return a list containing the first element
        of each tuple in *tagged_sentence*.

            >>> from nltk.tag.util import untag
            >>> untag([('John', 'NNP'), ('saw', 'VBD'), ('Mary', 'NNP')])
            ['John', 'saw', 'Mary']

        """

        return [w[0] for w in tagged_sentence]

    def evaluate(self, gold):
        """
        Score the accuracy of the tagger against the gold standard.
        Strip the tags from the gold standard text, retag it using
        the tagger, then compute the accuracy score.

        :type gold: list(list(tuple(str, str)))
        :param gold: The list of tagged sentences to score the tagger on.
        :rtype: float
        """
        gold_tokens=[]
        full_gold_tokens=[]

        tagged_sents = self.tag_sents(self.untag(sent) for sent in gold)
        for sentence in gold:#flatten the list

            untagged_sentences, goldtags,type_feature,startpos_feature,sentence_feature,senindex_feature = zip(*sentence)


            gold_tokens.extend(zip(untagged_sentences,goldtags))
            full_gold_tokens.extend(zip( untagged_sentences, goldtags,type_feature,startpos_feature,sentence_feature,senindex_feature))





        test_tokens = sum(tagged_sents, []) #flatten the list
        getmismatch(gold_tokens,test_tokens,full_gold_tokens)
        return accuracy(gold_tokens, test_tokens)

    #
    def new_feature_detector(self, tokens, index):
        return getfeatures(tokens, index)


    def tag_sents(self, sentences):
        """
        Apply ``self.tag()`` to each element of *sentences*.  I.e.:

            return [self.tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
        """
        return [self.tag(sent) for sent in sentences]

    def tag(self, tokens):
        # docs inherited from TaggerI
        tags = []
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i))
        return list(zip(tokens, tags))

    def tag_one(self, tokens, index):
        """
        Determine an appropriate tag for the specified token, and
        return that tag.  If this tagger is unable to determine a tag
        for the specified token, then its backoff tagger is consulted.

        :rtype: str
        :type tokens: list
        :param tokens: The list of words that are being tagged.
        :type index: int
        :param index: The index of the word whose tag should be
            returned.
        :type history: list(str)
        :param history: A list of the tags for all words before *index*.
        """
        tag = None
        for tagger in self._taggers:
            tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index)
            if tag is not None:  break
        return tag

    def choose_tag(self, tokens, index):
        # Use our feature detector to get the featureset.
        featureset = self.new_feature_detector(tokens, index)

        # Use the classifier to pick a tag.  If a cutoff probability
        # was specified, then check that the tag's probability is
        # higher than that cutoff first; otherwise, return None.

        if self._cutoff_prob is None:
            return self._classifier.prob_classify_many([featureset])
            #return self._classifier.classify_many([featureset])


        pdist = self._classifier.prob_classify_many([featureset])
        tag = pdist.max()
        return tag if pdist.prob(tag) >= self._cutoff_prob else None
```

Comment: So, do you call MySklearnClassifier.train method couple of times on different chunks of dataset? self._vectorizer and self._encoder is DictVectorizer and OneHotEncoder?

Comment: @Olologin yes I did call it

Comment: why are you trying to encode labels into binary? all classifiers may work on integer labels.

Also, if you want to partial_fit your classifier on subsets of dataset - you should call partial_fit every time (even at first time), and you should provide list of classes into it at first call. Thus you should know set of possible classes in your entire dataset at first call to partial_fit.

Comment: @Olologin where am I encoding labels to binary? is my 2nd code excerpt  for partialfit correct?

Comment: X = self._vectorizer.transform(X)
            y = self._encoder.transform(y)

Comment: here >y = self._encoder.transform(y)

Comment: @Olologin This could be any encoder, not necessarily a binarizer. Naive Bayes classifiers from sklearn will binarize the labels internally anyway (hence the number of rows of `Y` in the traceback).  
You have a point though: we're definitely missing some context as to how this code is actually called.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. The `RuntimeWarning`

You're getting this warning because `np.log` is called on 0:

```
In [6]: np.log(0)
/home/anaconda/envs/python34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  if __name__ == '__main__':
Out[6]: -inf
```

That's because in one of your call, some classes are not represented at all (they have a count of 0) and thus `np.log` is called on 0. You don't need to worry about it.

#### 2. Class priors

> I am using the following modified training function as I have to maintain a constant list of labels\classes as the partial_fit does not allow adding new classes\labels on subsequent runs , the class prior is same in each batch of training data

- You are right that you need to pass the list of labels/classes from the start if you're using `partial_fit`.
- I'm unsure about the class prior being the same in each batch of training data. That could have several different meanings, it would be nice if you could clarify what you meant here.
  In the mean time, the default behavior for classifiers such as `MultinomialNB` is that they fit priors to the data (basically they compute frequencies). When using `partial_fit`, they will do this computation *incrementally* so that you get the same result as if you had used a single `fit` call.

#### 3. Your error

> Also on the second call to partial_fit it throws following error for class count=2000 , and training samples are 3592 on calling model = self.train(featureset, classes=labels,partial=partial)

Here we need more details. I'm confused that `X` is of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` and yet in the traceback it appears to be of shape `(2000,11430)`. That means `X` has 2000 samples.

The error indeed means that the dimensions of your inputs are inconsistent. I would suggest printing `X.shape`, `y.shape` **after vectorization** for each `partial_fit` call.

Also you should not be calling `fit` or `fit_transform` on the vectorizer that transforms `X` for each `partial_fit` call: you should fit it **once**, then just transform X. This is to ensure that you get consistent dimensions for your transformed X.

#### 4. Your 'earlier' solution

Here's the code you told us you were using:

```
class MySklearnClassifier(SklearnClassifier):
    def train(self, labeled_featuresets, classes=None, partial=False):
        """
        Train (fit) the scikit-learn estimator.

        :param labeled_featuresets: A list of ``(featureset, label)``
            where each ``featureset`` is a dict mapping strings to either
            numbers, booleans or strings.
        """

        X, y = list(compat.izip(*labeled_featuresets))

        if partial:
            classes = self._encoder.fit_transform(np.unique(classes))
            X = self._vectorizer.transform(X)
            y = self._encoder.transform(y)
            self._clf.partial_fit(X, y, classes=list(set(classes)))
        else:
             X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
             y = self._encoder.fit_transform(y)
             self._clf.fit(X, y)

        return self._clf
```

As far as I can tell there's not much wrong with that, but we really need more context as to how you're using it here.
A nitpick: I feel it'd be clearer if you put the `classes` variable as a class attribute, since this variable needs to be the same for each `partial_fit` call.
Here you might be doing something wrong if you pass different values to the constructor `classes` argument.

More information that could help us help you:

- Prints of X.shape, y.shape.
- Context: how are you using the code you provided??
- What are you using for `_vectorizer`, `_encoder`? What classifier are you ultimately working with?

Comment: i was using earlier code MySklearnClassifier, I did not get the time to test my second ,will soon update

Comment: After many tries I was able to get the following code working, by accounting for first call but I had assumed that the classifier pickled files would be increasing in size after each iteration but I am getting the same sized pkl file for each batch which is not possible:, updated the third version, using multinomial NB

Comment: It would still be useful to have an example of the specific code you use to train your model and perform prediction. Are you still getting the error? As for the pickle size, it's the expected behaviour: think about what is stored in the file. It doesn't store the data, only the coefficients it needs to make a prediction. The number of coefficients depends on the number of features and on the number of classes, but not on the number of samples. You could try making predictions and each step and printing the error on a **held out** dataset to see if your model evolves as expected.

Comment: yes I was able to run based on the 3rd version  as posted above , i dumped  each of the partialfit function calls result , each file is some 12 MB , but without using partial fit it is 85mb.

Comment: also the outputs for partial_fit and fit are not matching at all for the test data

Comment: Could you post the code you actually use to run these experiments?

Comment: also if using the same training data as test data it is not at all correctly predicting and giving almost the same class distrbution for the top 5 classes for each test sample from the training sample. I am currently using very less training data of about 1000 sentences only. So I suspect there are some problems with the scikit transformation.

Comment: I've seen your code, unfortunately I can't figure out what's going wrong. As a general guideline, it's better to post _only_ the code that causes the issue. Ideally the smallest sample of code that allows reproducing the issue,  though it's probably difficult in your case. In the code you posted the relevant part is probably the _train method. If you think your problem is with `partial_fit`, you could try to apply it on a dataset you get from the `sklearn.datasets` utilities: it's just an exercise but it makes it much easier to figure out where/if you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, I believe, can be seen in the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2000,11430) (2000,10728) (2000,11430)
```

Note the (2000,11430) (2000,**10728**) (2000,11430), you supply a dataset with a different amount of features, therefor it can not determine the amount of features since they are different in the second set, and this gives the error. It only shows the error and does not crash because the error is most likely catched in a `try catch` block.

You probably do not want to give a different set of features (attributes) to the `partial_fit` function. Your algorithm still performs because it fitst on the remaining two chuncks, but the second chunck is most likely ignored.

Comment: I checked the featureset before vectorization and they were same sized

Comment: What does `print X.shape` give you just before `partial_fit`?