# Using comparable frozensets as feature values in machine learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have features whose values are frozenset , this causes the training function of scikit to fail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//PycharmProjects/assortclassifier.py", line 237, in _train
    model = self.train(featureset, classes=labels, partial=partial)
  File "/home//PycharmProjects/assorted/tclassifier.py", line 94, in train
    X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
  File "/home//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 224, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "/home//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 172, in _transform
    values.append(dtype(v))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

v is a frozenset:

```
v=frozenset([u'HY', u'N'])
```

so how to train using frozenset or should I convert the frozenset to say a hash and hence losing the possibility of knowing the feature value? or convert it to a sorted tuple?
This may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697093/errors-encountered-in-partial-fit-in-scikit-learn)

Also I would want the classifier learn that frozenset([u'HY', u'N']) is similar to frozenset([u'HY']) if i store the hash i may not be able to achieve this as both hashes wont be comparable(my assumption).

Comment: You could store the set in a map with the hash as the key.

Comment: Binarize it with OneHotEncoder, or use FeatureHashing if nuber of possible binary features is too big.

Comment: @PeterWood  I would want the classifier learn that frozenset([u'HY', u'N']) is similar to frozenset([u'HY']) if i store the hash i may not be able to achieve this as both hashes wont be comparable(my assumption)

Comment: please update as to how a set can be hotcoded in scikitlearn ? would that preserve the comparability of the feature values? @Olologin

Comment: @Olologin so the hotcoder should have 2 bits set for frozenset([u'HY', u'N']) but only one for frozenset([u'HY']) ? or will it assign a bit based on the hash of the entire frozenset?

Comment: @stackit, You should distinguish between types of features. As far as i understood you - it's categorial features, and when you are trying to binarize features - you will get something like binary feature for any possible categorial value, among all values in training set. You will get 2 bits in both cases.